# Getting average runtime of instances of test method using a TestNG Factory

Tags: java, testng

I'm currently running a set of tests using a Factory. How can I record the time taken for each test, and then report the average time take for each test over every instance of the class. For example:

```
public class TestFactory {
    @Factory
    public Object[] create() {
        return new Object[] {
            new TestClass("1"), new TestClass("2")
        };
    }
}

public class TestClass {
    private int x;

    public TestClass(int i) {
        x = i;
    }

    @Test(priority=1)
    public void test1() {
        System.out.println("test 1 : " + x + "!");
    }

    @Test(priority=2)
    public void test2() {
        System.out.println("test 2 : " + x + "!");
    }
}
```

This would produce the output:

```
test 1 : 1!                    (assume this ran in 1 second)
test 2 : 1!                    (assume this ran in 2 seconds)
test 1 : 2!                    (assume this ran in 0.5 seconds)
test 2 : 2!                    (assume this ran in 1 second)
```

I know I can use @AfterMethod and ITestResult to calculate the runtime for each method in an instance and get the runtimes for both test1 and test2. But how would I calculate the average runtime of all instances that test1 and test2 ran so that I know that the average runtime for test1 was 0.75 seconds and for test2 it was 1.5 seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`@org.testng.annotations.Listeners`](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners).

#### Implement suite listener

```
public class AverageReport implements ISuiteListener {
    @Override
    public void onStart(final ISuite iSuite) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(final ISuite iSuite) {
        // group runtimes per method
        Map<String, List<Double>> runtimes = new HashMap<>();
        for (IInvokedMethod method : iSuite.getAllInvokedMethods()) {
            ITestResult result = method.getTestResult();
            long runtime = result.getEndMillis() - result.getStartMillis();
            String methodName = method.getTestMethod().getMethodName();
            runtimes.computeIfAbsent(methodName, (name) -> new ArrayList<>())
                    .add((double) runtime);
        }

        // calculate averages and report
        averages.forEach((methodName, value) ->
            value.stream()
                 .mapToDouble(a -> a)
                 .average()
                 .ifPresent(avg -> 
                       // Put your reporting code here
                       System.err.println(
                           methodName + " average runtime is " + avg + "ms"
                       )
            ));
    }
}
```

#### Annotate your suite

And then you can use this annotation on your factory like this:

```
@Listeners(AverageReport.class)
public class TestFactory {
    @Factory
    public Object[] create() {
        return new Object[] {
            new TestClass(1), new TestClass(2)
        };
    }
}
```

After all tests will finsh you'll get an output like this

```
test2 average runtime is 31.0ms
test1 average runtime is 26.5ms
```

Comment: Is there an easy way to only get the test methods from the suite as opposed to all invoked methods? I'm not concerned with how long my BeforeMethod, etc. took. Other than that, this did exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: To answer my own question, it looks like you can do `method.isTestMethod()` to see if the method is a test method.

Comment: @endorphins no problem :) you can use `method.isTestMethod()` to check if it is a test method.

Comment: @endorphins yeah :D

Comment: IMO, ITestListener or IInvokedMethodListener are better listeners for the purpose http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#testng-listeners